# How to play these notes?

Tags: piano, fingering

[image]

This is basically a G minor chord with a G in the bass.

Should I use my left hand to play the bass G and right hand to play the G minor triad?

Or should I play the bottom 2 notes with my left hand and top 2 notes with my right hand? Like strictly left hand for bass clef and right hand for treble clef.

Not sure what the convention is

Answer (score 3):

As with so many things in music, it depends on the context. You can play this either way: with three voices in the right hand and one in the left hand, or with two voices in either hand.

Your decision would likely be up to what chords occur before and after this one. If all of the surrounding chords are easier to play with three voices in the right hand and only one in the left, then you'd probably want to play this chord that way, also.

Answer (score 1):

You could do either.  The preferred method is going to depend on what comes next - there's no particular rule.

In some scores the upper three notes will be on a single stem (even when divided between staves) - in that case you can assume they're all played by the right hand.  The same is true when the two lower staff notes are on a single stem.  But in what you posted you're basically looking at four separately notated voices, and you'll do whatever is most comfortable in context.

Answer (score 1):

There is no convention. This seems to be a choral setting and the beams are referring to the 4 voices SATB. But you can play it the way you want. As other say: it depends of the context (what comes next?)